# How to test the convolution theorem using Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to prove that if `DFT(y)=DFT(x) * DFT(h)` then `y=x * h`.
I used the `np.fft.ifft` property but the second expression doesn't evaluate to True. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import cmath


X=[1.+1.j, 2.+3.j,1.+2.j]
H=[2.+3.j,1.+1.j,3.+3.j,4.+5.j]

Y=sp.convolve(X,H)
y=np.fft.ifft(Y)
x=np.fft.ifft(X)
h=np.fft.ifft(H)
print(y==sp.convolve(x,h))
```

It prints `'false'` but it should print `'true'`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No pun intended, but this code is a bit convoluted. Also, you seem to be comparing complex floats arrays which is an issue

Comment: Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue exactly but you should look up the intricacies of how floating point computations work.  Long story short do not use equality comparison on floating point numbers unless you know what you are doing as rounding errors will often prevent such equality checks from working the way they should.

Comment: Try to plot both results ! If plots are similar, this is definitely a floating point number comparison problem. Use np.isclose() for float comparison

Answer (score 3):

Why should it print `True`? As the convolution theorem says, convolution in one domain (e.g., time domain) equals point-wise multiplication in the other domain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem. So you need to e.g. multiply in the frequency domain and convolve in the time domain as below:

```
X=[1.+1.j, 2.+3.j, 1.+2.j, 3.+2.j]
H=[2.+3.j, 1.+1.j, 3.+3.j, 4.+5.j]

Y=np.array(X)*np.array(H)
y=np.fft.ifft(Y)
x=np.fft.ifft(X)
h=np.fft.ifft(H)

print(y == sp.convolve(np.hstack((x[1:], x)),h, 'valid'))
```

Here I made `X` and `H` of equal length to make element-wise multiplication possible and padded `x` to make the convolution circular. As far as I understand, `sp.convolve` always performs linear convolution, but the convolution theorem needs a circular one to hold.

You should also take into account that floating point operations are imprecise, so exact comparison of two results usually doesn't make sense. Better use something like this:

```
print(np.abs(y - sp.convolve(np.hstack((x[1:], x)),h, 'valid')))
```

This will print zeros, but if you select a different computation method

```
print(np.abs(y - sp.convolve(np.hstack((x[1:], x)),h, 'valid', 'fft')))
```

It will print some values representing calculation errors, very small but not zero.

Comment: @JakeLarson, glad to know it! Please notice that here "thanks" is expressed by upvoting and accepting the answer :)