# What kind of boundary condition or mode is used to perform convolution for fourier transforms?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft, convolution

I am trying to test the convolution theorem in Python. The convolution theorem says FT(f * g) = FT(f) convoloved with FT(g).

I wrote the following python code and the above equation is not satisfied. I used periodic boundary conditions 'wrap'. I am confused where went wrong. a,b are 2x2 numpy arrays

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
np.fft.fft2(a*b)
signal.convolve2d(np.fft.fft2(a), np.fft.fft2(b), mode ='same', boundary = 'wrap')
```

[image]

I want to know where went wrong and a correct example.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55893520/8786919

Comment: Per Omo Walker, does this answer your question? [How to test the convolution theorem using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893304/how-to-test-the-convolution-theorem-using-python)

Comment: @Davis Herring This is not a duplicate, despite having a similar title. The other is 1D, and this is 2D. Also, the problem here is a multiplicative constant difference (the convolution returns 4x the product), meanwhile on the other question the problem was not knowing what the convolution theorem does, so the other answer does not answers the problem here.

Comment: That does not answer my question. I also used circular boundary condition but not working

Comment: @corralien That is not a good duplicate, it does not answer this question. Please reopen! In the dupe target, the different was rounding errors. Here the difference is a 4x scaling.

Comment: If reopened I can post an actual answer, but in short: this relation is not satisfied for the DFT, though it would work for the (continuous domain) FT. What does work for the DFT is `fft(convolve(a,b))==fft(a)*fft(b)` (ie in reverse from what you’re doing).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Why this is the case, is there any reference I can have a look at?

Comment: It’s related to the scaling in the DFT. The forward transform doesn’t scale, the inverse transform scales with 1/N. So you can’t just invert properties like you can in the continuous domain case.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I tried it with 2x2 arrays but I stopped working for 3x3 arrays. Do you know what might have caused this?

Comment: You tried what? Did you divide each FFT output by the size of the array? What I’m saying is that you are not testing the convolution theorem. The convolution theorem is the inverse, as I pointed out earlier: `fft(convolve(a,b))==fft(a)*fft(b)`. Or rather more commonly, `convolve(a,b)==ifft(fft(a)*fft(b))`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I divide each FFT by the size of the array, the relation is still not satisfied

Comment: I don’t know why you expect it to be satisfied.

Comment: @CrisLuengohttps://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html equation 9