# What is the discrete form of the convolution theorem in using np.fft?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft, convolution

First, this is not a duplicate! I found similar questions on this site but they do not answer this question.

I tried to use the convolution theorem in Python. I have two N*N arrays where I can change the value of N.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sp
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
np.fft.fft2(a*b)
sp.convolve2d(np.fft.fft2(a), np.fft.fft2(b), mode='same', boundary='wrap') / 9
```

The /9 arises becasue Numpy `fft` uses backward normalization and I need to divide the number of elements here. However, the above two do not agree. I don't know where I went wrong.

I need to note that the above code somehow works when N = 2, i.e. when the size of the array is 2x2.

Also, FT( convolve(a,b) ) = FT(a) times FT(b) holds, but the alternate form I have here does not hold FT(a times b) = convolve( FT(a) , FT(b) )

I want to know where I went wrong and a correct example for FT(a times b) = convolved (FT(a), FT(b))

Comment: @Winniebear at the moment which approach should give the right result?

Comment: @cards sorry about aa and bb, it was a typo and I have changed it. For now, no approach gives the correct result. The discrete convolution theorem I used above only gives the correct result for a 2x2 array.

Comment: @Winniebear could you provide some references of that convolution "version"? The new edit add confusion with `.*` and `convolved`. Are they equivalent?

Comment: @cards https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html, The version I said is equation(9). I have updated the question.

Comment: In  mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html, this symbol: `*` means convolution, not product, but the convolution theorem should work both ways, because the FFT is his own inverse, except for a constant that depends on the implementation.

Comment: @vakvakvak Thanks. Now I just use 'times' in the question to avoid confusion

Comment: Look, it’s unfortunate that [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77893186/7328782) got incorrectly closed as duplicate, but I don’t think it’s right to ask the question again, you should wait for it to be reopened. At least delete the other post, so we don’t have identical questions here.

Comment: Note that this is not the convolution theorem. The convolution theorem compares convolution in the spatial domain to multiplication in the frequency domain.

Comment: @vakvakvak the FFT is not its own inverse. The forward and backward transforms are similar, but not identical. You're saying that `fft(a)==ifft(a)*C` for some constant `C`, but this is obviously not true.

Comment: @Cris Luengo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform cite: "Since **the inverse DFT is the same as the DFT**, but with the opposite sign in the exponent and a 1/n factor, any FFT algorithm can easily be adapted for it."

Comment: @vakvakvak Note the part **with the opposite sign in the exponent**. It’s not just the scaling. —— And this difference is apparently enough to make OP’s equivalence incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

FFT( convolution(a,b)) = FFT(a) * FFT(b)

```
np.fft.fft2(a)*np.fft.fft2(b)
array([[2025.   +0.j        ,   13.5 -23.3826859j ,   13.5 +23.3826859j ],
       [ 121.5-210.44417312j,    0.   +0.j        ,    0.   +0.j        ],
       [ 121.5+210.44417312j,    0.   +0.j        ,    0.   +0.j        ]])

np.fft.fft2(sp.convolve2d(a,b, mode='same', boundary='wrap') )
array([[2025.   +0.j        ,   13.5 +23.3826859j ,   13.5 -23.3826859j ],
       [ 121.5+210.44417312j,    0.   +0.j        ,    0.   +0.j        ],
       [ 121.5-210.44417312j,    0.   +0.j        ,    0.   +0.j        ]])
```

Comment: Yes, I found it is strange that this version of the convolution theorem holds. But FT( a*b) = convolved (FT(a), FT(b)) is not